# Filtering AD property from get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

so i am writing a script,
in our company we store users home-directory on network drives,
and when they leave we rename the directory by adding .left to the folder name,
example: "name.left"
and we actually used to do so by finding the user in AD 
copying the content of the home directory property and renaming it.
so i got this so far :

```
$name = Read-Host 'User Name: '
$path = Get-ADUser $name -Properties homedirectory
Rename-Item $path {$name+".left"}
```

problem is when i get the home-directorys path in get-aduser it gives it with the standart get-aduser output, it just adds it to the output so i tried using filter :

```
$path = Get-ADUser $name -Properties homedirectory -Filter homedirectory
```

and it gave me an error, but not for the filter, now it doesn't recognize the user name i gave it.

now, I'm sure that there is a way to filter the string in the property.
and i get a feeling that the third line i wrote might be wrong as-well, 
but that's my python brain trying to work with powershell :)  so if enyone could help me with that one, i would really appreciate it, 
and if anyone can point me to good powershell guides that would be really nice.

**EDIT:**
so i fixed it to look like that :

`$name = Read-Host 'User Name: ' 
$date = Read-Host 'Date Please: '
do { $path = Get-ADUser $name -Properties homedirectory | select -Expand HomeDirectory $newname = {$name + "LFT" + $date}
 Rename-Item $path $newname
 Write-Host $name + 'changed' } 
while ($name -ne 'exit')`

and i get an error that the new name is a script and not a string so it cant run, you know a way to fix it?

Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no 
input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:6 char:19
+ Rename-Item $path $newname
+                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

**EDIT2**
a fellow employee helped me out and this is the result: 
it does exactly what i needed :)

```
$name = Read-Host 'User Name '
$homefolder =  (Get-ADUser $name  -Properties HomeDirectory).homedirectory
$date =  Get-Date -UFormat "%d.%m.%Y"
ren $homefolder -newname ($homefolder + "_lft_" + $date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `select-object` you can filter out unwanted properties. It will still return an object tho. It has a handy argument named `expand` that will return single properties value:

```
$path = Get-ADUser $name -Properties homedirectory | select -Expand HomeDirectory
```

Comment: thank you very much! the string i got is the exact string i wanted!